# HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL php error

Tags: php, http, post

I am attempting to edit and display data from google fusion tables with the following code:

```
<?php

include('Lib/clientlogin.php');
include('Lib/sql.php');
include('Lib/file.php');

//get token
$token = ClientLogin::getAuthToken('usernane', 'password');
$ftclient = new FTClientLogin($token);

//show all tables
echo $ftclient->query(SQLBuilder::showTables());
echo "<br />";

//describe a table
echo $ftclient->query(SQLBuilder::describeTable(2683865));
echo "<br />";

//select * from table
echo $ftclient->query(SQLBuilder::select(2683865));
echo "<br />";

//select * from table where test=1
echo $ftclient->query(SQLBuilder::select(2683865, null, "'test'=1"));
echo "<br />";

//select test from table where test = 1
echo $ftclient->query(SQLBuilder::select(2683865, array('test'), "'test'=1"));
echo "<br />";

//select rowid from table
echo $ftclient->query(SQLBuilder::select(2683865, array('rowid')));
echo "<br />";

//delete row 401
echo $ftclient->query(SQLBuilder::delete(2683865, '401'));
echo "<br />";

//drop table
echo $ftclient->query(SQLBuilder::dropTable(358731));
echo "<br />";

//update table test=1 where rowid=1
echo $ftclient->query(SQLBuilder::update(2683865, array('test'=>12), 1));
echo "<br />";

//insert into table (test, test2, 'another test') values (12, 3.3333, 'bob')
echo $ftclient->query(SQLBuilder::insert(2683865, array('test'=>12, 'test2' => 3.33333, 'another test' => 'bob')));

?>
Hide details
Change log
r8 by kbris...@google.com on Apr 7, 2011   Diff
updates to library
Go to:  
Older revisions
 r4 by kbris...@google.com on Dec 17, 2010   Diff 
 r3 by kbris...@google.com on Dec 17, 2010   Diff 
All revisions of this file
File info
Size: 1321 bytes, 50 lines
View raw file
```

When I run this I get the error:

```
HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Error 405
```

I have used the php "POST" command before on this server with out issue. If anyone has any ideas as to what might be going wrong your help would be appreciated.

Edit: Below is the code for the query() function. I believe this is where the error is originating:

```
function query($query, $gsessionid = null, $recursedOnce = false) {

    $url = SCOPE;
        $query =  "sql=".urlencode($query);

    $fusiontables_curl=curl_init();
    if(preg_match("/^select|^show tables|^describe/i", $query)) { 
          $url .= "?".$query;
      if($gsessionid) { $url .= "&gsessionid=$gsessionid"; }
      curl_setopt($fusiontables_curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=".$this->token));

    } else {
      if($gsessionid) { $url .= "?gsessionid=$gsessionid"; }

      //set header
      curl_setopt($fusiontables_curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 
        "Content-length: " . strlen($query), 
        "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
        "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=".$this->token         
      )); 

      //set post = true and add query to postfield
      curl_setopt($fusiontables_curl,CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($fusiontables_curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$query); 
    }

    curl_setopt($fusiontables_curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($fusiontables_curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
    curl_setopt($fusiontables_curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $result = curl_exec($fusiontables_curl);
    curl_close($fusiontables_curl);

    //If the result contains moved Temporarily, retry
    if (strpos($result, '302 Moved Temporarily') !== false) {
      preg_match("/(gsessionid=)([\w|-]+)/", $result, $matches);

      if (!$matches[2]) { return false; }

      if ($recursedOnce === false) {
        return $this->query($url, $matches[2], true);
      }
      return false;
    }

    return $result;
  }
```

Comment: can't see the code which sends `POST` request, neither the address which you're calling. please expand your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marek. I have included what I believe is the problematic posting function in revised code above. If you have any ideas about what I'm dong wrong I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your server is the issue. The error states that POST isn't available with that URL. I know that Google is touchy with POST commands, if you attempt to switch from GET to POST on normal searches, your search is rejected. Probably the same in this case.

Try using GET or check the call to the POST command, I don't see it in your code.

EDIT:

From: http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide.html

> The API statements are sent to the Google Fusion Tables server using HTTP GET requests (for queries) and POST requests (for inserts, updates, and deletes) from a Web client application.

There you have it, like I suggested, you have to use GET to retrieve the data, and use POST only to send commands to edit the data. Change the query() function to use GET, and then write a separate edit() function that uses POST to edit the data.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have included the code for the query() function in the code above. I believe this is where the error is coming form. Any suggestions would be appreciated.